# VSCode run python file after single line execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

When using VSCode with the Python plugin I'm experiencing a very annoying bug, which is known in the community but was hoping to find a workaround.

Basically, when I run a single line execution with VSCode, the terminal enters into python interpreter and executes the line. After this I'm unable to execute the file in the terminal as VSCode doesn't automatically exit the python interpreter but I have to do so manually with quit() or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. This can be quite annoying.

```
>>> /usr/bin/python3 /home/debian/Documents/Tutorial/tutorial.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /usr/bin/python3 /home/debian/Documents/Tutorial/tutorial.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In order to replicate the issue use VSCode in a linux environment and execute a single line of code by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then try to run the file by pressing the rune file button on the top right.

A fix would be that VSCode would run the single line executions in a seperate terminal, as with PyCharm or have it exit the interpreter prior to executing the file.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's just how it's supposed to be. To execute the file, you simply open a new terminal.

Comment: @JayVasant i'd have to open a new terminal and type out the entire command. I was hoping to find an easier way as explained in the last paragraph of my question. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found two workarounds.

1. The first one is to run the file without debugging by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
   which can still be annoying as it takes a bit longer to load.
2. The second one is to install the extensions "Code Runner" Code runner lets you run the file in a seperate terminal. And add the following to your settings file to have it working just like PyCharm.

```
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "python3"
    },
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true
```

The question is open for more answers if anyone find a way to get this working by edditing some settings without the use of extensions.